# Job recent searches doesn't work right

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Steps to reproduce

1. First go to the jobs tab
2. Enter any search term
3. Hit enter

The **Your Recent Searches** does not get updated.  It's only after you move away from this page and come back to this page is the recent searches updated.

Comment: Confirmed. I'll put it up on the bug board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, build pushed to prod. Thanks for the (many!!) reports :)

Comment: Looks much better!